# Использование метода onCreate()

Tags: java, android

Есть код:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  set.ContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);
```

- Зачем вызывать родительский метод?
- Кем обычно вызывается этот перегруженный метод?
- Зачем вписывать переменную `Bundle` в аргументы метода?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Методы обратного вызова жизненного цикла активити (`onCreate()` `onResume()` `onPause()` `onStop()` и др.) вызываются системой для того, чтобы программист мог выполнить свой код в момент, когда активити находится в одном из состояний: создается, восстанавливается, приостановлена (потеряла фокус), остановлена (пропала с переднего плана) и др.

То есть система как бы говорит: вот когда активити будет создаваться, не хотите ли выполнить какие то действия? - тогда пишите их в методе `onCreate()` и я вместе со своими делами (вызов родительского метода `super.onCreate()` ) сделаю и ваши инструкции. Аналогично и с другими методами жизненного цикла.

Здесь существует обратная зависимость - не программист вызывает метод для какого то действия, когда оно ему требуется, как это обычно бывает, а система , в определенные, заранее установленные моменты, выполняет код программиста. Таким образом, код в методах жизненного цикла будет выполнятся всякий раз, когда в приложении ( в активити) наступают события какого то жизненного цикла.
Например, пользователь нажал на кнопку "домой" - ваша активити пропала с экрана - система вызвала методы `onPause()` `onStop()` , если вам требуются какие то действия в такой ситуации ( например, закрыть БД, сохранить текущие значения и тп.) вы пишите код, реализующий эти действия в методе `onStop()` и теперь всякий раз, когда активити будет пропадать с экрана - будут выполняться написанные вами действия.

Вызывать родительские методы необходимо, так как помимо ваших нужд у системы есть и свои, она тоже не прочь воспользоваться таким удобным случаем, как что то выполнить, такое ей нужное, когда активити только создалась, к примеру. В общем то все дела системы не скрыты от любознательного читателя и их легко можно найти в исходниках андроид, в реализации класса `Activity`.

Так же, некоторые методы имеют аргументы. Практически все аргументы методов жизненного цикла дублируются отдельными методами обратного вызова ( например бандл помимо `onCreate()` передает `onRestoreInstanceState()` и включены они скорее для удобства разработчика, чтобы не дергать лишние методы и не заводить поля класса для передачи их туда, где они потребуется с большей доли вероятности. Однако, нужен вам бандл или нет, получить вы его обязаны, таковы правила игры - есть только одна сигнатура для переопределения - с аргументом, который передает бандл, поэтому никакие другие варианты не переопределят системный метод, а создадут аналогичный пользовательский метод ( с одинаковым названием) , который будет известен тем, что никогда не будет вызываться системой и в этом плане ( как метод жизненного цикла) будет полностью бесполезен - нам это не надо.

PS: сам когда то долго не мог понять назначение жизненных циклов и принцип работы, постарался объяснить подоходчивей - не знаю правда, насколько получилось.

Answer (score 3):

> зачем вызывать родительский метод?

Он инициализирует (переводит в определенное состояние) жизненный цикл Activity

> кем обычно вызывается этот перегруженный метод

Операционной системой. Опять же в момент, когда Activity инициализирована.

> зачем вписывать переменную Bundle в аргументы метода?

Вы имели в виду, как используется эта переменная? В нее можно что-то записать перед завершением Activity, например в onSavedInstanceState.