# Начало программирования под Android

Tags: java, android, activity

В общем, я обучаюсь по книге "Head First программирование под Android", почему по ней? А потому что она новая, и рассчитывал на то, что я избегу многие неприятности с "устаревшими" приёмами, библиотеками и т.д. Но не тут то было, по книге мне надо создать ListActivity(нужен макет со списком напитков), а как я понял, он уже устарел, т.к. теперь там много других активностей и из них более мене подходит Master/Detail Flow, но он создает много активностей и макетов, что никак не вписывается в задачу. Подскажите, что в этом случае делать?

У меня все проекты создаются дэфолтно с расширением класса appcompatactivity, а в моей книге просто Activity, это как то связано с обновлениями? Может кто подробно про это рассказать?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Начнем с того, что Java вы начали изучать скорее всего не с того, что сразу начали GUI писать в JavaFX и организовывать клиент-серверное взаимодействие, а с самых основ и простейших примеров в консоли. При обучении разработки под Android вам стоит поступить так же - делать простейшие примеры, постепенно усложняя задачи. Фактически фреймворк Android отдельная эко-система, которая только использует язык Java для написания кода и все это требует отдельного обучения "с нуля".

Учиться я бы вам посоветовал по книге от BigNerdRanch: [Б.Харди - "Android. Программирование для профессионалов" - 2015 (2-ое издание)](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/135513511/) - это, пожалуй, единственная достойная книга на русском языке для новичка. Обучение построено на том, что ставится конкретная задача (какое-то приложение) и последовательно, шаг за шагом, с подробными объяснениями, эта задача реализуется. В результате вы напишите реальное работающее приложение (всего их пять, если мне не изменяет память, исходники всех приложений доступны на GitHub и легко находятся по названию) и даже будете понимать, как это делать самому. Так же эта книга даст вам целостное представление об устройстве приложения и взаимодействии его частей, в отличие от книг-справочников или уроков в интернете, где дается разрозненная информация о отдельных элементах, оставляя самому думать о том, как все это соеденить в работающее и не пугающее остальных, кто увидит код, приложение :) При небольшом усердии можно найти бесплатную электронную копию этой книги.

Насчет устаревших классов и или наследников. То, что в реальной разработке использовать `ListActivity` вам вряд-ли придется, не зависимо от ее устаревшести, так как она наименее гибкая в реализации списка, мы здесь опустим.
Дело вот в чем - базовый класс экрана Android-приложения - класс `Activity`. Используя только этот класс вы безусловно можете реализовать весь необходимый функционал.  Наследующиеся же от базового `Activity` классы лишь добавляют немного какой то функциональности, например, `ListActivity` реализует слушатель и упрощает подключение разметки, в основном - это делается и в обычной активити в несколько строчек кода. Что касается `AppCompatActivity` - она создана для того, чтобы поддерживать *Material Design* на устройствах с API < 21 (до Android 5.0, где этот дизайн по дефолту) вместе с библиотекой поддержки *AppCompat* и обеспечить взаимодействие `ActionBar` с этой библиотекой поддержки. Не думаю, что дизайнерские изыски первоочередная задача при начале обучения, главное для вас - научиться работать с фреймворком, украсить вы всегда успеете. Так же стоит заметить, что если вы не собираетесь распространять свои уроки, то беспокоится об обратной совместимости вообще нет нужды.
При начале обучения не стоит обращать внимание на "устаревшесть" информации или классов - принципы в базе остаются неизменными и ничего кардинально нового "новые" классы не несут. Напротив, понимание работы с "устаревшими" классами облегчат использование "новых", так как вам нужно будет только понять, что (и зачем) добавилось. В случае с `AppCompatActivity` вообще можно с некоторыми незначительными оговорками считать ее за `Activity`, то есть использовать равнозначно.

Таким образом в обучающих проектах вы можете с полной уверенностью использовать класс `Activity`, `ListActivity` и любой другой, который требуется для понимания задания, не обращая внимание на его устаревшесть. Когда вы будете понимать принципы работы с фреймворком достаточно, чтобы писать собственное приложение, вы без труда сможете определиться, какой именно тип активити вам нужен для каждого отдельного экрана, не стоит сейчас на этом заморачиваться. Если вас смущает дефолтное создание активити , то просто удалите первых девять букв (оставив `extends Activity`) и измените тему приложения с AppCompat, на какую-нибудь из Holo, либо не обращайте на это внимание вовсе - `AppCompatActivity` естественно реализует все базовые методы `Activity` и на работу примера это никак не повлияет, как правило.

Насчет шаблонов - единственный шаблон, который стоит использовать - Blank Activity, для чего остальные остается тайной за семью печатями :) - новичок не сможет их осилить ввиду крайней перегруженности, человек опытный реализует все самостоятельно, как ему нужно для конкретной задачи, это проще, чем адаптировать чужую заготовку под свое решение. Все эти шаблоны крайне избыточны и неоправданно запутаны.

Насчет уровня знания Java. Владение базовыми возможностями языка на хорошем уровне вполне достаточно для написания полноценного приложения. Наиболее актуально знание самого фреймворка, его классов, структуры приложений, взаимодействие с системой, принципы верстки макетов и тп. В частности [жизненный цикл](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/432813/177345) вызывает много непониманий в начале.

Гугл создал очень хороший портал [разработчика Android](https://developer.android.com/index.html?hl=ru), который включает как полное описание API, так и множество гайдов, примеров и инструкций. Кроме того, здесь вы всегда получите самую актуальную информацию, в частности [об отличиях](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html) `AppCompatActivity` от базовой `Activity` (краткое описание и какие методы добавились к наследуемым и кстати, обратите внимание на цепочку наследования). Приятным бонусом будет то, что портал активно переводится на русский язык и многие статьи можно прочесть на родном языке. Советую вам очень внимательно изучить его после прочтения книги выше и обретения начального понимания принципов разработки под этим фреймворком. Начать можно [отсюда](https://developer.android.com/guide/index.html?hl=ru)

Ну и здесь есть огромное количество как готовых ответов, так же как и людей, всегда готовых ответить на хороший новый вопрос.

PS: если какие то моменты не достаточно понятны, пишите в комментариях, дополню ответ.

Comment: >  измените тему приложения с AppCompat, на какую-нибудь из Holo
можно про это поподробнее?

Comment: @Иван в */res/values/styles.xml* напишите вместо чего то вроде :`<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">` следующее: `<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">` или какая вам тема нравится. Все остальные стили там можно удалить

Answer (score 8):

1. Да, ваша книга уже устарела в части активити. Использовать же дефолтные проекты студии сможет только профессионал - там слишком много нюансов и вам будет крайне сложно как-то их изменить так, чтоб они не перестали работать. Ваш путь - пустая совсем активити. И в ней уже творить.
2. Большинство сейчас используют `AppCompatActivity` в виду её обратной совместимости. Во многих деталях и нюансах код по `Activity` не будет работать для `AppCompatActivity`.
3. Смотря что вы имеете в виду под "простые приложения". Вывести список на экран из массива сможете. А вот свою камеру или клиент к сайту... Сможете, но познаете все круги ада и соберетё здесь множество репутации за десятки вопросов. Если вопросы будут качественные и по делу.

Comment: 1) Я обратил внимание на это потому, что в книги написано "Списковые активности определяют свой макет на программном уровне, поэтому вам не придется создавать или заниматься сопровождением разметки XML", а так же "Вам не нужно реализовать собственного слушателя".

Comment: @Иван, этим удобно пользоваться только если вы понимаете как оно внутри работает. Вполне вероятно, что вы не наткнётесь на какие-то нюансы, но, если наткнётесь, то разобраться почему нечто "неработает" вам будет очень сложно. Так что я бы не советовал вам ими сейчас пользоваться.

Comment: Я к тому, что как раз этот макет "ListActivivity" и определяет всё это.
То есть, в моем случае проще написать пустой макет и  что то на уровне: 3 кнопки на весь экран с передачей интента для каждой вместо списка? я просто не совсем понимаю.
P.S. И если не секрет как вы изучали андройд, я понимаю, что вы не новичок, всегда интересно узнать откуда профи берутся.

Comment: @Иван, ну, вы можете попробовать, но, вроде, нету класса ListActivity, расширяющего `AppCompatActivity`. Т.е. вы будете изначально работать-учиться на не самом популярном ныне API. Переход, в последствии на современные версии может быть нелёгок. А андроид я изучил гугля и прочитав одну книгу какую-то. Т.е. придумал себе задачу и довёл её до релиза самостоятельно.

Answer (score 3):

Знаком с книгой книге "Head First программирование под Android" не по наслышке. Сам использую ее при обучении. Книги этой серии отличаются от других по стилю изложения материала и это многих подкупает. Был рад, когда в свет вышло издание 2016 года т.к.издание 2011 года сильно устарело. Но к удивлению обнаружил, что и это издание порой содержит описание устаревших методов. Это не значит, что стоит выбрасывать все книги)) , наоборот стоит их использовать. И если андроид студия "обнаружит", что вы пользуетесь устаревшим методом, она вам это сообщит и иногда даже предложит варианты. И уж ваша задача будет разобраться как решить проблему при помощи новых методов.. тут уж никакая книжка не поможет..только сами,гугл и сообщество. В начале конечно будет трудно писать свой проект поэтому можно просто набрать простые примеры из книжек, они будут работать. При этом вы освоитесь в Андроид студио. А после придумайте проект и реализовывайте его потихоньку.. поверьте столкнетесь с такими проблемами, что порой ни в одной книжке не найти)) .. Но в любом случае будете искать ответ и в них тоже..

Answer (score 1):

Отвечу на 3. (Так как сам новичок по сути).

Можешь пытаться писать что - то вроде простеньких утилит (Фонарик и тд.).
Можешь сделать простенькую игру в стиле Угадай число" и тд.

И да, было бы интересно занести тебя в свои контакты и пообщаться.