# Кто вызывает public методы в Activity?

Tags: android

Скажите, пожалуйста, каким образом вызываются public методы в Android? Мне не понятно. Если читать литературу по java, то метод должен вызываться через объект, например "объект.метод". Но в андройде же достаточно только описать public метод и он будет вызываться сам по себе, как указано в примере ниже. 
Скажите пожалуйста кто вызвал метод `onCreateOptionsMenu`? Где указан вызов данного метода? Почему он вызвался? Где про это почитать?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        menu.add("menu1");
        menu.add("menu2");
        menu.add("menu3");
        menu.add("menu4");

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это системные методы-колбэки (методы обратного вызова, о чем, как правило, говорит приставка *on-* в имени метода). Их вызывает система при наступлении определенных системных событий.

Например, `onCreateOptionsMenu()` вызывается системой, когда в приложении необходимо создать меню (которое вызывается при нажатии системной кнопки "меню").

Происходит следующее: когда в приложении требуется отобразить меню, система начинает выполнять определенные манипуляции, в одном из этапов которых происходит срабатывание колбэка `onCreateOptionsMenu()`, здесь программист приложения может внести свой код, который будет выполнен наравне с системным, при создании меню и который, как правило, определяет, что это меню будет в себе содержать (пункты)

Смотрите так же [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/432813/177345) по системным колбэкам. Так же можете прочитать все, что найдете поро жизненный цикл активити, системные колбэки и любую книжку по андроид-разработке, где обо всем этом говорится довольно подробно. Могу порекомендовать книгу Б.Харди "Android.Программирование для профессионалов" - 2016г, 2-е издание

Answer (score 3):

На самом деле хороший вопрос, потому что это не совсем очевидно, даже если прочтете про жизненный цикл `Activity`.

Итак, вкратце:
Первое что происходит это создается объект `Activity`. При этом отрабатывает только его конструктор и ничего больше:

```
Activity activity = new Activity();
```

Но обычно никто не создает объект в таком виде. Вместо этого все идет через `Intent`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(previousActivity, Activity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Если предыдущего `Activity` (в данном случае `previousActivity`) нет, то система просто запускает выбранный Activity.class, по сути также через intent.

Только после `startActivity(intent)` отрабатывает метод `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)`, т.е. иначе говоря именно этот `startActivity` его и запускает по сути. На самом деле цепочка чуть длиннее:

> startActivity -> create() -> onCreate()

По сути у разработчика нет доступа к методу create(), он даже называться может по другому, в любом случае этот метод создает Activity и запускет `callback` `onCreate`;

Далее как только `onCreate` отрабатывает он запускает *callback*, который в свою очередь запускает метод start(), тот запускает *callback* `onStart`, `onStart` в свою очередь запускает `callback`, запускающий resume() ну и дальше запусается *callback* `onResume`.

Насчет `onCreateOptionsMenu` все не так очевидно, так как в различных версиях Android запуск выглядел по разному. Намеренно опуская старые версии можно точно сказать, что с Android 3.0+ [согласно документации](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html) запускается при старте Activity, т.е. в методе start() в порядке отображения элементов app bar (обычно в качестве app bar используется саппортовский `Toolbar`)

Answer (score 0):

Почитайте о жизненном цикле Activity. Насколько я понимаю onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) вызывается автоматически при создании Activity. как и много других функций. Зайдите на startandroid.ru/ там много чего полезного.

Answer (score 0):

Ваш класс MainActivity - расширение класса Acrtivity. Activity - это экран, что-то вроде форм в Windows. Например, браузер, в котором вы сейчас сидите. Метод `onCreate` вызывает система Android при запуске приложения. `onCreateOptionMenu` вызывается каким-то классом, отвечающим за отображение всего.